# how to load records with has_many relation under nested resource route

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I thought the helper path will load all `logs` which is `belongs_to` the parent record `remote_focu`

```
tool_cvt_remote_focu_remote_focu_logs_path(tool_cvt_remote_focu)
```

But it didn't, it still loads all the records of the remote_focu_logs.

What's wrong ?

### ROUTE

```
  namespace :tool do
    namespace :cvt do
      resources :remote_focus do
        resources :remote_focu_logs
      end
    end
  end
```

### INDEX ACTION IN log controller

```
  def index
    @tool_cvt_remote_focu_logs = Tool::Cvt::RemoteFocuLog.all
  end
```

And If I want to keep the normal routes for direct access without , should I add the duplicated-like route rule in route.rb

```
  namespace :tool do
    namespace :cvt do
      resources :remote_focu_logs
    end
  end
```

Comment: what is in your controller?

Comment: new controller was created by scaffold , I didn't change any

Comment: just put index action to question, because with routes all looks fine

Comment: @IS04 Hi I updated it.

Answer (score 1):

instead:

```
def index
  @tool_cvt_remote_focu_logs = Tool::Cvt::RemoteFocuLog.all
end
```

should be something like:

```
def index
  @tool_cvt_remote_focu_logs = Tool::Cvt::RemoteFocu.find(params[:remote_focu_id]).remote_focu_logs
end
```

scaffold just generate some basic functions common for each resources

Comment: I want to show all the `remote_focu_log ` belongs_to `tool_cvt_remote_focu `

Comment: and how index would get params? - here 'Tool::Cvt::RemoteFocu.find(params[:remote_focu_id])'

Comment: `tool_cvt_remote_focu_remote_focu_logs_path(tool_cvt_remote_focu)` - id will get from `tool_cvt_remote_focu`

Comment: Hi I updated it, what if I want to keep normal route and nested routes both avaliable.

Comment: you could check if `remote_focu` exist in `params` or just create separate controller